# JWPlayer Reading From PHP And Then Updating Via Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, jwplayer

First up , I'm new with JWPlayer with PHP and I'm using JW6 ,

What i require is , Reading JWPlayer Variables from a PHP File and then for the visitor to update those specific variables(such as rtmp link and player size) By Button Clicks On page.

For Eg: I Create a Php File As load.php And Have the JWPlayer Read from it . How can this be done?

I've searched and found that there is a similar post for specific video files(mp4) To load onto the JW Player Via PHP , With the Code Below .

```
<?php
    header("pragma : no-cache");
    header("Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT");
    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header("Content-Type: video/mp4");
    header("Content-Location: videos/testvid.mp4");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-Length: ".filesize("videos/testvid.mp4"));
    readfile("videos/testvid.mp4");
?>
```

But What i require is for a HLS Link (m3u8) File To be read via PHP (For the 'file' variable in JW6) Along with The Player Sizes To Be Read So that i would be able to add buttons on the page that would change(update) Those variables the player will update on page itself , with NO Refresh required.

How could i accomplish this task?

Regards.

Comment: You might want to look into this - http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1439570-example-loading-new-playlists, but since you are using PHP, the player's type variable has to be set to mp4, for example, since your file extension won't be mp4, if that makes sense.

Comment: That's very useful , thanks , but any idea on how i couild get it to work with m3u8 ?

Comment: Np. Yes, just set the type variable to hls instead.

Comment: Thanks buddy , helped me alot.

Comment: Now i've setup the Playlist switching by creating buttons and the function as per the link you sent me above and it works fine , but in my scenario each playlist has a specific sub domain in the link (Eg : abc.domain.com) the sub domain would represent the specific server , now im trying to figure out a way to update all those sub domains in the links(parameter) with a button to switch to a specific server , which will update that "abc" subdomain to another subdomain(my 2nd server , for eg: xyz) and so on , Can this be done  ? without the user requiring a reload/refresh .? Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think it would require a reload since they are coming from different domains.

Comment: What i meant is , If i set a button with a link to a video , that link will have a subdomain on it (eg : subdomain.domain.com/video.m3u8) now is it possible to update that subdomain attribute in the link with a button on page (Via jquery) to switch the subdomain , which in turn will switch the server.

Comment: Not really sure I follow this. You will still need to load the new file into the player.